# bat file behaviour differs when launched from cmdline or doubleclick

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a simple Windows batch file (batch.bat) that runs Gnuplot. In it I have;

```
gnuplot gnuplot_file.plt
```

When I manually launch a dos window with cmd, and type in the batch.bat command, this executes fine. When, however, I attempt to launch the batch file by doubleclicking on the bat file, it errors out claiming that

```
'gnuplot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

It could have something to do with the fact that I had to install Gnuplot with Admin credentials, and I'm currently running it as a normal user?

Would there be any global path parameters I can pass to let the doubleclick launched batch file instance know where to find the executables? I've tried SET, and as far as I can tell all the variables look to be identical with both launch methods

Thanks